# ¿Se pueden generar CSV con mas de una hoja, usando node.js?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, csv, backend

Buen día.
Necesito generar un CSV que lleva mas mas un millón de filas.
Excel por defecto tiene un limine de 1.048.576 filas, entonces necesito que cuando llegue a ese tope se cree otra hoja de cálculo y continúe llenando.

La forma que estoy usando para llenar el CSV es la siguiente:

```
fs.writeFile("src/controller/csvPrueba.csv", csv, function () {
          res.download("src/controller/csvPrueba.csv");
        });
```

"csv" es la variable donde están los datos.

Pero como lo comenté antes, al llegar al tope de filas simplemente deja de escribir y queda incompleto. :(
Desconozco si existe otra librería o forma hacerlo. Muchas gracias!

Comment: Víctor, no fui yo quien te votó negativamente, sin embargo, puede ser porque no mostraste ningún ejemplo de cómo estás creando el excel. Lo que sí te puedo decir es que puedes utilizar una librería como exceljs para crear archivos .xlsx. Ahí mismo puedes crear una nueva hoja cuando el conteo de filas llegue a un número específico. Suerte

Answer (score 0):

Los archivos .csv (valores separados por comas) pueden ser abiertos desde Excel pero NO SON un formato de Excel, sino bastante más antiguos. La limitación de las 1.048.576 filas es de excel, y no del archivo. Así que si lo que quieres es usar el archivo como intercambio de datos con alguien que lo abrirá en Excel, lo tienes complicado por su propia limitación.

En cambio, si tu aplicación genera correctamente el CSV y la necesidad es únicamente la de abrirlo (quizá para saber si está bien generado) o como intercambio con otra aplicación que se alimente de CSVs, puedes hacerlo con otros programas como [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/downloads/) u otros más específicos para abrir ficheros exageradamente grandes como [Large Text File Viewer](https://web.archive.org/web/20140908181354fw_/http://swiftgear.com/ltfviewer/features.html).